# How To Substitute Piped Output of Awk Command With Variable

Tags: linux, bash, unix, awk, sed

I'm trying to take a column and pipe it through an echo command. If possible, I would like to keep it in one line or do this as efficiently as possible. While researching, I found that I have to use single quotes to expand the variable and to escape the double quotes.

Here's what I was trying:

```
awk -F ',' '{print $2}' file1.txt | while read line; do echo "<href=\"'${i}'\">'${i}'</a>"; done
```

But, I keep getting the number of lines than the single line's output. If you know how to caputure each line in field 4, that would be so helpful.

File1.txt:

```
Hello,http://example1.com
Hello,http://example2.com
Hello,http://example3.com
```

Desired output:

```
<href="http://example1.com">http://example1.com</a>
<href="http://example2.com">http://example2.com</a>
<href="http://example3.com">http://example3.com</a>
```

Comment: I have a file with a lot of lines. I just need to get column 2 and convert it into that <ahref... format. I just need it to be done for all lines and keep the same order (that's why I went for the loop). I'm open to whatever else you guys might think works better.

Comment: I'm still struggling to understand why you'd have thought you needed to pipe the awk output to a shell loop... You know awk is reading each input line one at a time in an implicit loop right? So even if you didn't know how to just do everything in that first command why would your instinct be to pipe the output of the first awk command to a shell loop instead of a second awk command? Btw - that is NOT how to write a shell loop or access shell variables and most importantly see https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169716/why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice.

Comment: @EdMorton, I didn't know it's reading each line in an implicit loop. I did understand the first part but didn't know the easiest ways to substitute. My mind went to `sed` first and then thought about `echo`. I need to continue to get better with `awk` substitutions and printing. I just don't do this often enough so sometimes it's flexing old muscles. SO has been amazing though since I'm self taught :-)

Comment: Yeah every time you see an awk statement like `condition { action }` you can imagine awk is providing the surrounding code that turns it into this behavior: `WHILE read $0; DO IF ($0 ~ condition) THEN action; ENDIF; DONE`. awk was designed entirely for manipulating text so all the stuff you commonly need to do to manipulate text (e.g. a while read loop and splitting the input into fields) is what awk provides for you automatically.

Comment: Ah, that's a really good explanation. Makes the `{ action }` very easy to understand as a loop. That makes a lot of sense. Now it's just a matter of knowing all the actions and how to use them well :-) Thanks for the quick lesson Ed. I really appreciate it as always.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$ awk -F, '{printf "<href=\"%s\">%s</a>\n", $2, $2}' file
<href="http://example1.com">http://example1.com</a>
<href="http://example2.com">http://example2.com</a>
<href="http://example3.com">http://example3.com</a>
```

Or slightly briefer but less robustly:

```
$ sed 's/.*,\(.*\)/<href="\1">\1<\/a>/' file
<href="http://example1.com">http://example1.com</a>
<href="http://example2.com">http://example2.com</a>
<href="http://example3.com">http://example3.com</a>
```

Comment: Yes! Literally that is what I was trying to do. I didn't know about the `%s` option. Very useful. I would totally accept your answer now haha